# Close div on click or tab outside

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, jquery-focusout

I've got a page with a pretty standard popup menu in the header. The specs say that the user needs to be able to close it in three ways:

1. by clicking outside the menu
2. by clicking the link that expands it a second time (slidetoggle)
3. by tabbing outside the menu

I have the first one working, but I can't seem to figure out the other two. When you click the link a second time, it slides up, and then slides back down. And I've tried using the jquery "focusout" to get the menu to close when the user tabs out, but no luck.

Here's my js:

```
$("#body").mouseup(function (e) {
    var subject = $("#shell-user-account-details");
    if (e.target.id != subject.attr('id') && !subject.has(e.target).length) {
        subject.hide();
    }
    $("#shell-user-account-details").attr('aria-hidden', function (i, attr) {
        return attr == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';
    }).attr('aria-expanded', function (i, attr) {
        return attr == 'false' ? 'true' : 'false';
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#shell-user-account-link', function (event) {
    $('#shell-user-account-details').slideToggle().attr('aria-expanded', function (i, attr) {
        return attr == 'false' ? 'true' : 'false';
    }).attr('aria-hidden', function (i, attr) {
        return attr == 'false' ? 'true' : 'false';
    })
});
```

And here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tactics/u4quaje0/2/

Thanks.

Comment: Update: I figured out how to get the menu to close on second click. Still haven't figured out the tab thing.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this for your second problem?

```
     $("#idofyourlink").click(function(){$("#idofyourpopup").toggle();})
```

on your third problem, have you tried setting the `tabindex` attribute of that menu to "0"? Then in your script, add the following:

```
     $("#idofyourmenu").blur(function(){$("#idofyourpopup").hide();});
```

Comment: The toggle solution doesn't work at all.

The blur solution works, but it creates a second problem: you can't tab on the links in the menu. Once you open the menu and click the tab button, it immediately closes the menu.

Comment: Definitely don't set an element to tabindex="0" that must be tabbable as you are taking it out of the Accessibillity flow.